# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "10/10/19 10:02" in android

Tags: java, android, datetime, kotlin

I am having an issue in parsing the date format. It's fine with English language devices but it creates issues on other language devices.

Below is the code:

Activity class:

```
try {
      callDayTime = Utils.DATE_FORMAT1.parse(callDate)
      time = Utils.DATE_FORMAT.format(callDayTime)
    }catch (e: Exception){
      Applog.e("MainAct", e)
    }
```

Utils class:

```
var DATE_FORMAT = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault())
var DATE_FORMAT1 = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy HH:mm", Locale.getDefault())
```

Below are the logs:

```
Non-fatal Exception: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "10/10/19
10:02"
       at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:358)
       at com.asn.helpers.MainActivity.getList(MainActivity.java:113)
       at com.asn.async.BackupHistoryData.doInBackground(BackupHistoryData.java:44)
       at com.asn.async.BackupHistoryData.doInBackground(BackupHistoryData.java:18)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
```

I also try to test on my device with different languages and time zone but didn't face that issue.

Comment: Why are you trying to parse the date string using two different formats?  Do you not know what the incoming format is?

Comment: Looks like, in use, you've switched the two formats around. Using the one for formatting to parse, and the one for parsing to format.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, i know the incoming format.

Comment: @bowmore Yes, i need to parse incoming format and then convert into other format.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Can you help to find out exact issue?

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: I can’t spot what’s going wrong in your code, I would have expected it to work. The format `dd/MM/yy HH:mm` shouldn’t contain anything language specific as far as I can see, so should work on all devices regardless of language setting.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. I hand translated your code to Java, and it runs without sign of error. I tried setting my JVM locale to Arab, Japanese and Hindi. `time` becomes `10/10/2019 10:02:00` each time. Tested on jdk-1.8.0_101

Comment: @OleV.V. That's exactly happening with me. It runs every time I try to run with my device. But it's not working on the live app when some users from outside countries are using.